# In Javascript, How to use a (global) function inside an object? The function would do complex stuff and would be used when creating objects

Tags: javascript, function, object, call

So, I was thinking of creating a function which does some stuff, and later use the same function inside different objects created later.

In the code below are two instances: Testing (01) and commenting out (02), and vice versa.

```
"use strict";

function fullName() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}

const person = {
    firstName: "Anant",
    lastName: "Ghotale"
    completeName: fullName.call(person) // (01) does not work
};

//person.completeName = fullName.call(person); (02) this works


console.clear();
console.log(person.completeName);
```

(02) works, but (01) doesn't.

That is to say, creating a new property outside `person` while using call to put this = person works, but not inside it.

These are my questions:

1. How do I use (call) a function inside an object?
2. Is this a foolish endeavour, to call a function inside an object? Is there a better way to do the same task?

Comment: You can make `completeName` a getter `get completeName() {... code ...}` and self reference your object using `this`

Comment: the specific problem, you're having is that `completeName` is being assigned the _result_ of calling `fullName.call(person)` at the moment of object declaration, which is before `person` has an assigned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for this.

```js
function fullName() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
}

const person = {
  firstName: "Anant",
  lastName: "Ghotale",
  get completeName() {
    return fullName.call(this)
  }
};

console.log(person.completeName)
```

Comment: But how do you call a function inside an object in general?

Comment: You cannot access the object while declaring it because it isnt yet created. You can use a getter or a normal function and inside you can use call, bind and apply since you call / run the code after the object was created in both cases.

Comment: Can you show an example? In the getter you used, it didn't make use of the `fullName` function. What I want to know is how you can call a function inside an object while passing the value of 'this' as the object inside which the function is called.

Comment: I have edited the answer according to your question.

Comment: Nice! I just tested the code and changed the getter into a regular method. The only change is to use `person.completeName()` instead.

Comment: Correct, that's what I meant by my first comment. Although, a getter is much nicer IMO. Since you don't need the parents. On the other hand in some cases you want to pass arguments, so then it would make sense of course. In that case I would use apply instead of call and pass the whole [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) array.